# How to have header in some particular pages?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

In document class "report", in some particular pages, I  would like to have two kinds of headers. I want that the header for the odd pages is as follows:

```
Title1 ................................................. Page number
```

and accordingly, the header for the even pages as follows:

```
Page number ............................................ Title2
```

I should to explain that title 1 is related to the "name of my report" and title 2 is fixed and is independent of the chapter name. In the following, I have mentioned my work:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, left=20mm, right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Blue,urlcolor=Blue,citecolor=Blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm,algcompatible}
\usepackage[textfont={small},labelfont={rm,small},format=hang,labelsep=quad,justification={centering},aboveskip=1pt,belowskip=1pt]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{cite}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}{}{1ex}{\bfseries\fontsize{15}{16}\selectfont}[]
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
This is my work.
\end{document}
```

How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Define  a page style (with `fancyhdr` or `titleps`) and apply it.

Comment: @ Bernard , Unfortunately, I do not know how can I do it. Can you please help me?

Comment: We can, but please post a minimal *compilable* example, with the relevant part of your preamble.

Comment: @Bernard , I edited my question. Thank you so much.

Comment: What would be these titles (1 and 2)? I suppose, not pre-deined, but depending on the chapter or section titles? And for which kind of pages should it be used?

Comment: @Bernard 6, I am sorry, I think that my question is not clear.  In fact, title 1 is related to the "name of my report" and title 2 is fixed and is independent of the season name. I am editing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with `titleps`, which is loaded  with the `pagestyles` option of `titlesec`. Likewise, the   `clearempty` option replaces loading the `emptypage` package.

Note the first page of chapters (if any) still have the `plain` page style (page number centred in the footer).  This can  be modified, either adding a command in `\titleformat{\chapter}` or re-defining the `plain` page style with `\renewpagestyle{plain}`.

I took the opportunity to simplify the options for `geometry`. Some other remarks: `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions (most notably `cleveref` should be loaded afterwards). Also, if you have maths in your document (I suppose so, since you load mathtools), you should use a maths font which fits `times` – I loaded `newtxmath` for that, which is based on the Times-clone `TeX Gyre Termes`, ad I'd recommend, if you're allowed to replace times, to load also `newtxtext`, to have true small caps and some other delicacies.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twoside, dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[vmargin=25mm, hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty]{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{algorithm,algcompatible}
\usepackage[textfont={small},labelfont={rm,small},format=hang,labelsep=quad,justification={centering},aboveskip=1pt,belowskip=1pt]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{times, newtxmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Blue,urlcolor=Blue,citecolor=Blue]{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[toc]{blindtext} %for demonstrating purposes
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}{}{1ex}{\bfseries\fontsize{15}{16}\selectfont}[]
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

\newpagestyle{myps}{%
\sethead[][\thepage\enspace\dotfill\enspace Title 2][]{}{Title 1\enspace\dotfill\enspace\thepage}{}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}%

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{alph}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{myps}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{A First Chapter}
\Blindtext[5][2]
\chapter{A Second Chapter}
\Blindtext[2][5]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, The following is an elementary answer:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, left=20mm, right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Blue,urlcolor=Blue,citecolor=Blue]        {hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm,algcompatible}
\usepackage[textfont={small},labelfont=        {rm,small},format=hang,labelsep=quad,justification=    {centering},aboveskip=1pt,belowskip=1pt]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{cite}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small  \leftmark \ \hrulefill\ \thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small  \thepage \ \hrulefill\ \rightmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} 
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}{}{1ex}{\bfseries\fontsize{15}{16}\selectfont}[]
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
%\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[3-56]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `\dotfill` command instead of `\hrulefill` for dotted header.